# Jquery autocomplete with json input + rails3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

```
$(function() {
  $('.autocomplete_address').autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    delay: 600,
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/welcome.js",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {search: request.search},
      success: function( data ) {
      var data_obj = jQuery.each(data,function(i, key) {
                     });
        response( $.map(data_obj, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.area,
            value: item.area
          }
        }));
      }


    });
      }

    });


});
```

**Using jquery-ui-186**'s autocomplete

The autocomplete part works But it shows the same results for any data entered

In the server side code looks like this:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @area =  Address.search params[:search]
    @area =  @area.as_json(:include => :state)
    @area =  @area.to_json

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js {render :json => @area}
    end
  end

end
```

**Where am i going wrong!!!!!!**
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request` object has a `term` property, not a `search` property. Update your AJAX call:

```
/*Snip */
data: { search: request.term },
/*Snip */
```

Comment: WoW... That works!!!!!!!!!!YAY...**Thanks very much** And  I'll vote this up once i reach 15 reputation points

Answer (score 0):

Update: make from the docs:

```
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
```

So yours might look like this:

```
 success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map(data_obj, function( item ) {
                       return {
                          label: item.area,
                          value: item.area
                       }
                 });
    }
```

It looks like you're not actually doing anything with the results of your .each().

Comment: Nope That's not it...Some how the data that is to be sent to the sever for lookup is getting sent Is `data: {search: request.search},` correct? I am not sure....

Comment: Nope That's not it...Some how the data that is to be sent to the sever for lookup is getting sent

Comment: I added that $.each block just to get the  objects separately in a variable so that i can work on that...Other that each() is not being used like you said....But It's working now thanks to @orolo